# Can I call a subroutine within a function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a function in vba that runs a subroutine and returns and then returns "success" if the subroutine runs, but when I try to execute the function in a worksheet i get #VALUE and the subroutine is not called.

Simple example code shown below:

```
Sub downonecell(a)
    Range("B10").value = a
End Sub

Function onebelow(b As Integer) As Variant
    Call downonecell(b)
    onebelow = "Success"
End Function
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel  With minor exceptions, a function called from a worksheet cell can't change the workbook environment other than by returning a value.  Calling a sub from the function doesn't release you from that restriction.

Comment: ^ this. functions take inputs, compute a result, return that result: if your code needs to be side-effecting, then you need a macro (a parameterless and ideally explicitly public `Sub` procedure, typically in a standard module) invoked from some button (or event handler), instead of a UDF calculated in a cell.